# C++ operator [] overload not responding

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I've created the class array and something is going weird.. the class is the following:

```
class array
{
    private:
        int *a_;
        size_t size_;
    public:
        array();
        array(const size_t);
        array(const arreglo &);
        ~array();
        int const &operator[](size_t)const;
        int &operator[](size_t);
        array const &operator=(const array&);
        bool empty()const;
};
```

The overload's implementation of [] are:

```
int const &array::operator[](size_t index)const
{
    std::cout << "getter" << std::endl; 
    return a_[index]; 
}
int & array::operator[](size_t index)
{
    std::cout << "setter" << std::endl; 
    return a_[index]; 
}
```

The way i'm testing the code is in this main:

```
int main()
{
    array a(7);
    a[0] = 3;
    a[1] = 6;
    a[2] = a[0] + a[1];
    array b = a;
    std::cout << b[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the opertar [] is just using the getter version and prints through cout "setter" and never "getter".
What is going wrong?

Comment: You need to spell your getter call like this: `const_cast<const array&>(a)[0]` etc.

Comment: Did you mean to say "The problem is that it is just using the *setter* version" ?

Comment: Also it would be good if you can explain what you are trying to achieve; if you leave aside the `cout` lines then the code performs the addition correctly

Comment: IMO, OP is having some language difficulties in the last paragraph. He expects the const operator to be used, he finds the non-const being executed.

Comment: Forgive the C programmer here, but can the compiler even select the correct overloaded function based on a different return type? I've been operating under the belief that the only thing that mattered were the function's parameters.

Comment: @user4581301 Not different return type, different `const` qualifier.

Comment: Thanks @Barry . Will do some reading and probably ask a question or two later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking of them as "getter" and "setter" variants is a mistake. The difference between the two is merely the cv-qualification of the function and the return type. They are both getters. More importantly, you are returning reference types.

References tend to decay, in this case to a mutable int, therefore the compiler is more likely to accept a non-const function call.

```
a[0];
```

The default evaluation of this statement is an integer value, not a reference, so that you can for instance do:

```
if (a[0])
```

and this is predicate on the value at a[0] rather than the reference (evaluating the reference would always be true and not very helpful).

Remember that when references are used in most statements they decay to the referred value.

```
int v = a[0]; // no error, even tho v's type is not int&
int& vr = a[0]; // decays to the value a references
                // then takes a reference of that
```

(Note: that the compiler may elide the implied set of operations to simply capture or imply the original reference in the second statement).

So the code

```
a[2] = a[0] + a[1]
```

It starts by getting the values from a[0] and a[1], knowing that it wants to do math, so the easiest way for it to do this is:

```
int a1 = a.operator[](1);
int a0 = a.operator[](0);
int& dest = a.operator[](2);
dest = a0 + a1;
```

If you want const, you're going to need either a const/const-ref to an array or to specify that you want a const ref:

```
const int& ar = a[0];

#include <iostream>

struct array
{
    int i = 0;
    array() {}
    const int &operator[](size_t) const { std::cout << "const int[]\n"; return i; }
    int &operator[](size_t) { std::cout << "int[]\n"; return i; }
};

int main()
{
    array a;
    a[0];
    int v1 = a[0];
    const int v2 = a[0];
    std::cout << "refs\n";
    int& v3 = a[0];
    const int& v4 = a[0];
    std::cout << "const array\n";
    const array b;
    b[0];
    int v5 = b[0];
    const int v6 = b[0];
    std::cout << "refs\n";
    //int& v7 = b[0]; // would produce a compile error
    const int& v8 = b[0];
}
```

See http://ideone.com/7EYGYj

Answer (score 0):

In short

```
void f(const array& b){
     std::cout << b[2] << std::endl;
}
```

b is required to be const.  All that is available is the const functions.

In your example it is a "read" but *b* is not const so the non-const is called. It is using the "setter" as the getter.